# Scale text inside container

Tags: javascript

The goal is to have a resizable container with some text inside that takes as much space al possible vertically or horizontally without wrapping to the next line.

[image]
[image]

After googling around I wasn't happy with the found solutions so I created my own and I was wondering if anyone can advice any improvements.

1. Set a really big fake font-size (f), for example 1000, to the target text
2. measure width (w) height (h) of the text container and divide by font-size (f):

   - iw = w/f
   - ih = h/f
3. Divide main container width (W) by iw and main container height (H) by ih:

   - kw = W/iw
   - kh = H/ih
4. Pick lowest between kw and kh: that is the wanted FontSize.

Here's a jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/pinkynrg/44ua56dv/

```
function maximizeFontSize($target) {

  var testingFont = 1000;
    $target.find(".text-wrapper").css("font-size", testingFont+"px");

  var textWidth = $(".text-wrapper").width()/1000;
  var textHeight = $(".text-wrapper").height()/1000;
  var width = $(".container").width();
  var height = $(".container").height();

  var kWidth = width/textWidth;
  var kHeight = height/textHeight;
  var fontSize = kWidth < kHeight ? kWidth : kHeight;

  // finally
  $(".text-wrapper")
    .css("font-size", fontSize+"px")
    .css("line-height", height+"px");
}
```

The solution I'm looking for have to:

- be agnostic to the font used.
- be fast so it can be used for user live resizable containers (for example a panel of a dashboard).
- mainly javascript. The only CSS I use is to say that the target text must not wrap to the next line.

Comment: This question might be better suited for the code review stack exchange - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah I didn't pick up what your question was @pnknrg

Comment: Mainly wondering if there can be code improvements. For example I don't like the point 1 where I set the initial font-size to 1000, it's kinda dirty.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is static we could find a way to make this work relying heavily on the `font-style` you're using and the parent/body `font-size` (because we are going to be using `ems` for the text).

*Although, it is indeed possible to calculate the respective width needed for different fonts, I will not show that here to keep it pragmatic.*

---

Let's say our markup looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">Some text</p>
</div>
```

Our body styles are:

```
body {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

For that text size, we'd need to calculate the max `ems` we can use for the text to be, in this case I kept it simple, as for `18px` I only need `1em`:

```
.text {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Then in JS we will have to abuse of the container's `font-size` property by using percentages and doing:

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
container.style.fontSize = container.offsetWidth + '%'
```

And then our text will occupy roughly the same width as the container.
It could be done even more dynamically but that depends on the needed solution.

---

[**Here's a JSFiddle for more clarification**](https://jsfiddle.net/GMaiolo/dmjgw6qe/)